# Excel: Compare count number of rows in which two columns have same text that is NOT a particular value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns each of which contains strings; sometimes the cell is empty.

I need a count of how many times the two columns have the same value, but NOT blank and NOT one particular value ("HR-L" must be excluded).

For example:

```
U1        R1

D-SW      D-SW
SH-N      SH-N
D-NE      SH-S
(blank)   (blank)
(blank)   P-NE
HR-L      HR-L
```

Should return 2, because in rows 1 and 2 the cells are identical and both "acceptable" answers. In row 4, I don't want to count when they are identical because they're both blank. In row 6, I don't want count when they're identical because they're both HR-L.

I tried:

```
=COUNTIFS(Table1[1U],"<>",Table1[1U],"<>HR-L", Table1[1U], Table1[1R])
```

But that is resolving `Table1[1R]` to one particular value and comparing each row of 1U to that particular value, rather than comparing Columns 1U and 1R within each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with `COUNTIFS` because `COUNTIFS` doesn't allow you to do a direct comparison between two columns - you can use `SUMPRODUCT` like this

`=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A10=B1:B10)*(A1:A10<>"")*(A1:A10<>"HR-L"))`